# Android XML Color shows up as gray?

Tags: android, colors

I'm trying to use Paint.setColor() with a color from res/values/colors.xml but it keeps coming out "grayish". If I use a string literal instead and use Paint.parseColor() it shows up correctly. What's going on?

onDraw()

```
p.setColor (Color.parseColor ("#82ef82")); // <- this works
p.setColor (R.color.PeaGreen); // <- this is gray
```

colors.xml

```
<color name="PeaGreen">#82ef82</color>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R.color.PeaGreen` is not a color, it's a resource id for a color resource. But since colors are represented by integers and so are resource id's, it's not throwing any warning or error. You need to do a little bit of work to get the actual color from a resource id:

```
p.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.PeaGreen));
```

There are also a few color constants defined in the [Color](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) class and you can use them like so:

```
p.setColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: Thanks, You're spot on. I should have known better.